# how to configure header section for a phonegap project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

what is the different between declaring  tags like this

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to use these libraries when implementing a local project. iam working with phonegap application.my tutorial is following the first method. how do i use these libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first method they are including the jquery lib from ajax.googleapis.com instead of using local jquery lib. This method will work only if you are connected to internet. In the second case you need to download the lib and give path of local file. So If you are sure your page will be opened only when user is connected to internet then only use first method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here jquery.min.js is file call from ajax.googleapis.com

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>


Here jquery.min.js file call from js folder from your app.
Download all libraries file and store in js folder in your ap
```